# How do I reload asp.net configuration file cache?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I have an asp.net application that sets the `configSource` attribute on the `rewriteRules` element in web.config to point to a separate config file:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules configSource="App_Data\Config\RewriteRules.config" />
</rewrite>
```

My web app makes edits to the `RewriteRules.config` file programmatically, but my web app does not pick up the configuration changes after the file is edited and saved.

I have tried calling `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain()` after editing the file. This successfully restarts my app domain, but the changes in RewriteRules.config are still not picked up. I have tried adding `RestartOnExternalChanges="true"` to the rewrite element, but this is apparently not supported on the IIS rewrite module. I have also tried `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("rewrite/rules")` but this does not seem to have any effect. The only way I can get the changes to take effect is to edit and save the main web.config file, but I am trying to avoid doing this programmatically for security reasons.

I am confused as to why `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain()` does not cause external config files to be re-read. Is this expected behavior? Does the config file cache somehow exist outside the bounds of the app domain? Is there any practical way to achieve what I am looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, the problem with your case is, related `configSection` definition is not marked as `restartOnExternalChanges="true"` in definition. For example; we created a custom config section for storing application urls in an external file and we create a section definition in web.config file like

```
<section name="pageUrlFormats" type="Kahia.Web.Configuration.PageUrlFormats.PageUrlFormatsSection, Kahia.Web" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="false" />
```

so that asp.net knows if any change occurs in related file:

```
<pageUrlFormats configSource="Config\PageUrlFormats.config" />
```

application domain restarts. This goes same for all config section definitions, including **UrlRewrite** module's definition.

What you have to do is, find definition of related module. In this scenario, it is at apphost.config at **C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config**

In that file, look for rule section definition, it starts like

```
<section name="rules"
```

You have to add `restartOnExternalChanges="true"` attribute to that config file.

Comment: By the way, i tested it with UrlRewrite module and this is not working for it due to native implementation of that module. Look for the accepted answer at [link](https://forums.iis.net/t/1155629.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

IIS7 configuration system uses the same syntax as the .Net framework configuration system, but is a different implementation that has some behavior differences.  The restartOnExternalChanges thing is a feature of the .Net framework configuration system that is not supported by the IIS7 configuration system.  The url rewriter module uses the IIS7 configuration system.